# How to create dynamic route in angular2?

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I want to create a project with dynamic route that only type name on url and then route will detect the url and create the own route access to that file to display to broswer

```
import { Routes,RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

const routes: Routes= GetDynamicRoute();

export const routing = RouterModule.forRoot(routes);

function GetDynamicRoute(){
  var results :Array<Object> = Array<Object>();
  var page = 'GET_URL_PARAMATER';

  results.push({ path: '' ,loadChildren: 'app/tmp/home.module'});
  results.push({ path: page, loadChildren: 'app/tmp/'+page+'.module' })
  return results 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a function called `resetConfig` inside of the `Router`.

See this Github issue with some plunkers inside: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/11437#issuecomment-245995186

And the official docs: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/router/index/Router-class.html#!#resetConfig-anchor